# What is the 12th Russian exception verb?

Tags: глаголы, мат, спряжение

There is a well-known poem that lists eleven Russian exception verbs:

> Гнать, дышать, держать, зависеть,
>
> Видеть, слышать и обидеть,
>
> А еще терпеть, вертеть,
>
> Ненавидеть и смотреть.

Their exceptional character is that they belong to the second conjugation despite not ending with **ить**.

A teacher of mine said that there is a famous 12th exception verb with the same properties and that any native speaker will instantly name it if asked what verb is missing in the poem. Asked what that verb is, the teacher suggested that we find it on our own. Curious, I tried, but failed.

Did my teacher joke, and, if not, what is that verb?

Comment: It might be useful to add that the endings should be unstressed while conjugating .I mean in the third person, like те'рпит,  слы'шит, ви'дит, otherwise you will get a list of verbs.

Comment: As a native speaker I have no idea. And, even if we of course learned about these verbs at school, I have no idea in what way they are exceptional. And I cannot say without googling what number of conjugations Russian has and in what they are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware about a verb any native speaker would think of immediately.

*Пиздеть* is not one of them. These exceptions have *-е-/-а-* in their infinitive endings and **unstressed** *-и-* in personal forms. The fact that the *-и-* is unstressed is crucial, because it is exactly what makes it the source of potential mistakes.

The *-и-* in the personal forms of *пизде́ть* ("to lie" or "to engage in idle chat") is stressed, and there are hundreds of verbs like that (*свистеть*, *кишеть*, *болеть* etc.)

There is another verb, *пи́здить* ("to beat up" or "to steal"), but it has the *-и-* in infinitive as well, so it's not that either.

The only edge case thing I can think of is *призреть*.

Its third singular form, according to some grammarians (Avanesov, Rosenthal), is *при́зрит* (not *призри́т*).

This verb is quite archaic by itself and no one these days really pronounces it this way even if they do use it, however, technically, it still falls under the same category.

But again, it's far from something "any native speaker would think of immediately".

Comment: The reason native speaker would name пизде́ть as 12th irregular verb, becase at is often used as double stressed to emphasise emotions (wich is uncomon for normal russian speach). And thus it is *sounds* like this 7 irregular verbs ending with -еть

Answer (score 4):

Everyone who learned in Russian school tried to memorize this list of irregular verbs by means of a verse like this, where the actual order can vary to some extent (but usually any version starts with "гнать").

All this verses are similar in one thing - it's about 11 verbs, not 12. Apart, of course, from obvious derivative like "изгнать", "вытерпеть" etc. So I'm not sure what your teacher means. Or just don't know it.

UPD: Aaaand I've suddenly realized what your teacher meant! **It's** [**"пиздеть"**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)!

Here's the relevant quote:

> Мнения о том, какую форму глагола — **пиздеть** или **пизди́ть** — считать
>   правильной, часто расходятся, порождая многочисленные споры: *одни 
>   причисляют глагол пиздеть к глаголам-исключениям II-го спряжения*.

For obvious reasons this was never in a verse taught in schools ;)

Comment: The ending is stressed in finite forms of *пиздеть*. It's no different from *свистеть*.

Comment: Or лететь,  шуметь, гореть,  etc.

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm not sure that I got you right - пиздеть is exactly with final stress

Comment: @Quassnoi ah I see what you mean!  I actually agree! However it seems to me that teacher meant exactly that word.